# Grid of resistors with removal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have an infinite square grid of ideal 1 ohm resistors and want to measure the resistance of the grid between two points, but one or more resistors have been removed. How does this affect the outcome?

Please retag. I'm spitballing with linear algebra.

Comment: what kind of grid is this? like a coordinate grid-type thing?

Comment: assuming a square grid like this one: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm

Comment: That depends on which resistors are removed. For example, if you remove all resistors connected to one of your measurement points, the resistance between that point and any others gets infinite.

Comment: Linear algebra is probably quite right on. It's gonna be solving a linear equation system / least squares problem with one or more rank 1-perturbations. There are several formulas for it. Probably a PhD student somewhere is already all over it.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/356/ <-- I assume you mean something like this (but not infinite) and some arbitrary resistors removed.

Comment: i've seen the problem for all the resistors in good conditions. But for an infinite grid with some of them broken no. I suspect the distance between the removed resistor and the points of measurement will affect final outcome. I found this work in the net "Resistance of Infnite Networks" by Sharma Maharaj :http://math.bard.edu/belk/projects/SharmaMaharaj.pdf

Comment: Another references http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/on-this-infinite-grid-of-resistors-whats-the-equivalent-resistance and https://www.mbeckler.org/resistor_grid/, the last with a simulation program.

Answer (score 4):

A special case of this problem has been posed in brain-teaser books:  The network of $1\Omega$  resistors is an infinite Cartesian grid, but the resistor between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ has been removed.  What is the net resistance between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$?

This problem can be solved by a combination of symmetry, superposition, and the parallel resistance formula.  By symmetry, in a complete grid of $1\Omega$ a 1 amp current sourced at $(0,0)$ will split into $\frac14$ amp along each of the four resistors emanating from that point, and a 1 amp current sinked at $(0,1)$ will split into $\frac14$ amp going into that point. Superposing the two, we find that the net resistance between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in the complete network is $\frac12\Omega$.

Now let our actual grid, with the missing resistor, have resistance $R$.  Then we can create the complete grid by adding our grid to a $1\Omega$ resistor going from  $(0,0)$ two $(0,1)$. The complete grid is a combination of that resistor and our desired grid, in parallel.  Thus
$$
\frac11 + \frac1R = \frac1{1/2} \implies R = 1
$$